# CXF Endpoint.publish starts new embedded server

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, embedded-jetty

I am using Embedded Jetty Server to deploy two webapps. This server has both Http(at 8080) and Https(at 8443) connectors. One app is a simple Http application and the other is providing SOAP services using CXFServlet. I found that Endpoint.publish either programmatically or through bean definition publishes on CXF's own embedded jetty server. Is it possible to publish my CXF soap web services to existing Jetty Server on same port i.e. 8443?

CXF version: 3.0.4
Jetty Version: 9.4.xxx

Comment: Do not use `Endpoint.publish`. Just use  `CXFServlet` and configure the endpoint using  `<jaxws:endpoint>`. See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html

Comment: Is there any difference?

Comment: In fact in the same. Sorry, I have not seen you had checked it with spring configuration. I am not sure what is your problem with the information you have provided. All application servers allow to publish several applications using http or https ports. CXF should not start an embedded server. May be is a jetty configuration issue